# Windows Forms in VB Updating Two tables

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I am creating a form in VB to enter customer sales invoices and need to update two tables i.e. InvoiceHeader and InoviceDetails.  The Invoice details can have more than one line for one Invoice header. I was wondering if there is any thing like Access subforms or how can I update both tables through an SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a few more details, but generally you could create a view of the tables in SQL and update through the view.
Or just write a procedure, in the SQL designer get the select statement showing what you want with both tables (You know inner outer Join) Then change it to update.

Comment: I think he's looking for the VB code to update/query his database.